# Playing a video in ipad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

I want to play a movie in my app and the video is stored in my ipad library.

Can anyone provide me the necessary guidance for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the `MPMediaItem` of the video you want using `MPMediaQuery`
- Get the Asset URL like this:

  `NSURL *videoURL = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];`
- Instantiate an [MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html) using `videoURL` as the content URL.

If the video is stored in your App's bundle then do this to get the URL:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"nameoffile" withExtension:@"mp4"];
```

Comment: i want to store the video in app bundle and then retrieve it how can i do it

Comment: i've updated my answer. you said in your question that the video is in your iPad's library, next time check your question before submitting :).

Answer (score 0):

See a sample of a custom view/viewController combo in [Pragmatic iPad Programming](http://pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad-programming). Check the source code for chapter 8 (free download from that page). They use a video provided as a file inside the project. Btw, if the file in the video appears red in XCode, you'll have to remove it and re add it, I think the project definition is a bit screwed.